# Static member function to initialize static member variable - usage and risks?

Tags: c++

In the case of 
In MyClass.h

```
class MyClass 
{
    static vector<type> types;
    static vector<type> createTypes();
}
```

In MyClass.cpp

```
vector<type> MyClass::types = createTypes();

MyClass::MyClass()
{
}
```

When will be createTypes() executed and does this method of initializing a static variable involve any risks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function will be called along with other static initializers, before `main()` starts. You don't risk anything more than with other means of static initialization.

Keep in mind tough that all static initializers should be designed to avoid triggering a SIOF -- Static Initialization Order Fiasco.

Static initializers in the same translation unit are executed in the order of their declaration in the file. However, initialization order across multiple translation units is **not** defined. A SIOF arises when a static initializer depends on another, which is in another translation unit.

Then, depending on the phase of the Moon, either both objects will initialize in the right order and everything will work, or they will initialize in the opposite order and you'll use a not-yet-constructed object -- Undefined behaviour ensues.

The SIOF-guard pattern avoids this by replacing static variables like the following :

```
std::list<Foo> gFoos;
```

... with a function that contains the variable as a local static :

```
std::list<Foo> &gFoos() {
    static std::list<Foo> theList;
    return theList;
}
```

This way, the variable is *always* initialized on the first call of the function, and it's impossible to access it before its construction.

Comment: All I need is to initialize a "const" std::container in VS2012 that does not support {} - initialization and somebody has told me that this is not a good practice. I didn't knew about SIOF but I read about it. My case isn't anything like that anyway.

Comment: @Zingam apart from having an odd single-purpose function (which you can declare as having no linkage to alleviate the problem), this seems fine to me. What arguments have been given ?